# .fadeOut() inside a hidden element - possible bug?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Given the [following code](http://jsfiddle.net/QMSzg/):

```
<div class='hotel_photo_select'>
    Hello
</div>

<div class='itsHidden' style='display:none'>
    <div class='hotel_photo_select'>
        Hello
    </div>
</div>
```

And:

```
$('.hotel_photo_select').fadeOut(300);
$('.itsHidden').show();
```

I would expect both `.hotel_photo_select` divs to be hidden. However, the second one is not hidden when I show the container.

Is this a jQuery bug? Every element should become hidden after fadeOut().

The only solution I think will be this :

```
$('.hotel_photo_select').fadeOut(300, function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
$('.itsHidden').show();
```

Which I find to be less than elegant.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You write `$('.itsHidden').show();` so of course one `Hello` will be shown. Please clarify your question a bit.

Comment: In my opinion, $('.hotel_photo_select').fadeOut(300); should fadeOut every element. In fact the one inside a hidden container is not hidden. That's the queston, but Boo solve the mistery :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, for this type of method you need to use '.each()'. Then also lets add a checkpoint, where we determine if the parent is visible, if its not visible, then we make it visible.

However, making the parent visible, could have a negative effect on your layout, YES. But there is no better way to do this, and therefore you should avoid these types of situations.

**Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/QMSzg/21/**

```
$('.hotel_photo_select').each(function () {
    var this_parent = $(this).parent('div');
    if (this_parent.is(':hidden')) {
        this_parent.show();
    }
    $(this).fadeOut(500);
});
```

Answer (score 8):

As "Boo" already mentioned, because the current state of second "hello" div is "hidden" jQuery.fadeOut() won't apply any animation on it.

Instead of saying "fade it out for me", you need to say "animate the opacity to 0". In this case jQuery won't care if your element is visible or not. it will do it's job:

```
$('.hotel_photo_select').animate({opacity:0}, 3000);
```

see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/QMSzg/20/

Comment: One thing to be careful of here is that at the end of fadeOut the element is set to display: none I believe. To mimick that you would need to a complete handler to then set the element to display none (depending on what you are doing with it afterwards).

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.fadeOut transforms elements from their current state to the state you want to adopt, in this case hidden. If the element is already hidden (as with the second occurence), jQuery don't need to perform any action. What you could do is specifically set the css display to none:

```
$('.itsHidden .hotel_photo_select').css('display','none');
```

Answer (score 1):

place the show() before the fadeout()

```
$('.itsHidden').show();
$('.hotel_photo_select').fadeOut(300);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
My solution was to hide the element as a call back function:

```
$('.hotel_photo_select').fadeOut(300, function(){
    $('.hotel_photo_select').hide();
});
```

This way if the element is hidden, the call back will be called right away.